# Large system of equations using wolfram alpha.

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to use Wolfram Alpha to solve a very large system of equations- Variables A through P with a Z. It has 40 equations, so it won't let me use the regular type in the first bar. I tried using the data input method, but then I got confused. Anyhow- here is what i have so far:

$a + n + k + h = z$, $d + e + j + o = z$, $m + b + g + l = z$

$p + i + f + c = z$, $b + c + i + l = z$, $f + g + m + p = z$

$h + l + b + n = z$, $g + k + a + m = z$, $n + o + e + h = z$

$j + k + a + d = z$, $e + i + c + o = z$, $f + j + d + p = z$

$j + k + n + o = z$, $k + l + o + p = z$, $a + m + d + p = z$

$a + b + m + n = z$, $b + c + n + o = z$, $c + d + o + p = z$

$a + e + d + h = z$, $e + i + h + l = z$, $i + m + l + p = z$

$b + e + l + o = z$, $c + h + i + n = z$, $a + b + c + d = z$

$e + f + g + h = z$, $i + j + k + l = z$, $m + n + o + p = z$

$a + e + i + m = z$, $b + f + j + n = z$, $c + g + k + o = z$

$d + h + l + p = z$, $a + f + k + p = z$, $m + j + g + d = z$

$a + b + e + f = z$, $b + c + f + g = z$, $c + d + g + h = z$

$e + f + i + j = z$, $f + g + j + k = z$, $g + h + k + l = z$

$i + j + m + n = z$

But then it turns the data into columns? I don't know where to go from here. (link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MnMz.png)

Help?

Comment: @vadim123: Indeed, and on Wolfram Alpha, no less - they purposefully limit its abilities, otherwise why would anyone pay for Mathematica?

Comment: I actually don't know the easiest way to put this into Wolfram Alpha, but I guess it would be easier for you to put this problem into matrix form.  Have you had basic linear algebra?

Comment: Is there another place you'd recommend me to go to solve this many at once?

Comment: Is this a system of equations for a $4\times 4$ magic square?

Comment: Here is a [list](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html) of free linear algebra software packages, any one of which can solve this system.

Comment: I would go with an open source Computer Algebra System (CAS) such as [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) or [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). It'll be much easier to save your results and explore more problems.

Comment: Yes this is a system for a 4 x 4 magic square. I need to do this for an extra credit assignment.

Comment: The 40 equations are for more than the usual patterns (rows, columns, diagonals, blocks). Can you describe how you chose these 40 combinations?

Answer (score 1):

In Maple, I get the following solutions:
$$
\left\{ a=-k+1/2\,z,b=-l+1/2\,z,c=j+k-1/2\,z+l,d=1/2\,z-j,e=1/2\,z-o,
f=k-1/2\,z+o+l,g=-j-2\,k+3/2\,z-o-l,h=j+k-1/2\,z+o,i=-j-l-k+z,j=j,k=k,
l=l,m=j+l+2\,k-z+o,n=-j-k+z-o,o=o,p=-l-k+z-o,z=z \right\} 
$$